Why is it that in some problems that involve systems of equations, solving for one unknown value, also yields the other in the second solution?
Like take the following scenario as an example:
Two spherical objects have a combined mass of 200 kg. The gravitational attraction between them is $7.34 × 10^{−6}$ N when their centers are 15.0 cm apart.
$$
M + m = 200
$$
$$
7.34 × 10^{−6} = \frac{GMm}{0.15^2}
$$
Solving for M through substitution, the resulting quadratic equation gives its value as one solution, but also gives m as the second solution, even though I was just solving for M. If I recall correctly, there are some problems like this where this is not the case and one would have to plug in the value into the original equation to get the second value, I suppose when it's more than just adding them together, or is it always the case, and if so, why?

"but also gives m as the second solution"  What do you mean?  If $M+m = 200$ then solving by substitution I let $m=200-M$ and plug that into the other to get $7.34\times 10^{-6}=\frac {GM(M-200)}{0.15^2}$ and solve solve for $M$ but.... it doesn't give a solution for $m$.  There is no $m$ any more.  What exactly do you mean?

@fleablood: I think the OP means the following: The quadratic equation for $M$ has two solutions, say $M_1$ and $M_2$, and the solutions for the system are $(M,m)=(M_1,M_2)$ and $(M,m)=(M_2,M_1)$. (Which is caused by the fact that $M$ and $m$ appear symmetrically in the two equations in the system.)

@fleablood When I solve for M, I get two solutions, and the second solution also equals m, and I didn't understand why that was the case for many problems of this type.

Oh... well, that's because role those variables play is perfectly symmetric as @HansLundmark noted.   As $M+m = m+M$ you can label either one either way and the same thing of $Mm = mM$.  A non symmetric equation wouldn't  $x^3 + 2y^2 \ne y^3 + 2x^2$ so you can just relabel those.

Note that your system of equations is invariant under the exchange $M \leftrightarrow m$. In other words, the variables are indistinguishable, meaning that they play similar roles. In consequence, after substitution, it is not possible to assign the solutions to each variable anymore (or, more precisely, all the permutations constitute valid solutions mathematically), without invoking further assumptions such as $m < M$ for instance.

" the variables are indistinguishable, meaning that they play similar roles" The two sentences have different meanings.
